# WCF Authentication - An error occurred when verifying security for the message

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication

I have a problem connecting to my WCF service with `clientCredentialType="UserName"`.

When I run the code below I get an error

> FaultException: An error occurred when verifying security for the message.

When playing around with some of the binding values I also get `Access is denied.`.

Fiddler says there is no authorization header and I cannot find the username or password in the request either.

Here are excerpts from my config:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
    <services>
      <service name="InventoryServices.MobileAPI"  behaviorConfiguration="customBehaviour">
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="basicHttpBinding"
                  bindingConfiguration="secureHttpBinding"
                  contract="InventoryServices.IMobileAPI"/>

        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpsBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="customBehaviour">
          <serviceSecurityAudit auditLogLocation="Application" serviceAuthorizationAuditLevel="Failure" messageAuthenticationAuditLevel="Failure" suppressAuditFailure="true" />
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
               customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="InventoryLibrary.Helpers.UserAuthentication,InventoryLibrary"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="secureHttpBinding">
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="Basic" realm="MyRealm"/>
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"  />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

My username/password validator looks like so:

```
  public class UserAuthentication : UserNamePasswordValidator {
        public override void Validate(string userName, string password) {

            EntitiesContext db = new EntitiesContext();
            db.Logs.Add(new DomainModels.Log() {
                DateLogged = DateTime.Now,
                Message = "hit auth",
                Type = DomainModels.LogType.Info
            });
            db.SaveChanges();

            try {

                if (userName == "test" && password == "test123") {
                    Console.WriteLine("Authentic User");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new FaultException("Unknown Username or Incorrect Password");
            }
        }
    }
```

I have this as a simple test on my service:

```
[OperationContract]
[XmlSerializerFormat]
void Test();

[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "test")]
public void Test() {

}
```

I have a self signed SSL certificate on my server and I can access my service/metadata.

Then I have added a service reference in a console application, and attempt to connect to the service with this code below:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        Stuff.InitiateSSLTrust();

        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
        binding.Security.Transport.Realm = "MyRealm";

        ServiceReference1.MobileAPIClient serviceProxy = new ServiceReference1.MobileAPIClient(binding, new EndpointAddress("https://xx.xx.xx.xx/InventoryServices.MobileApi.svc"));

        serviceProxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "test";
        serviceProxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "test123";

        try {

            var a = serviceProxy.Login("a", "b");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            var ex2 = ex;
        }
    }
}

public class Stuff {
    public static void InitiateSSLTrust() {
        try {
            //Change SSL checks so that all checks pass
            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback =
                new RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(
                    delegate { return true; }
                );
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

I've checked the event viewer on the server and this error appears with each request:

> MessageSecurityException: Security processor was unable to find a security header in the message. This might be because the message is an unsecured fault or because there is a binding mismatch between the communicating parties. This can occur if the service is configured for security and the client is not using security.

Comment: What does your client web/app.config look like?  There should be some values for the cert in there for the message security binding.   Also, have you got permissions on the certificate store on the server setup correctly? (I think its typically the "My" cert store. This sounds very similar to issues I have had in the past and is a bugger to nail. I'm trying to recall it as I type. It might form in the next 10 whilst I think about it.

Comment: Sorry I didnt see that the server binding was TransportWithMessage. However, I did notice your client was only using a Transport binding which is not the same binding as the server?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are specifying the client side to use `BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport` whereas the service is expecting `BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential`. This is a problem because the service is looking for the client credentials in the SOAP Message Header and the client will not send them with the binding configured this way.

Hence, this is why the username/password pair is not present in the Message Header as you are witnessing. So the event viewer was correct that there was a binding mismatch between the communicating parties.

Also set the `ClientCredentialType` on the client to `BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName` for `Message` level security. By default `BasicHttpBinding` uses `None` which are anonymous clients.

Here's a code snippet describing the above changes:

```
var basicHttpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding(
                              BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential);
basicHttpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = 
                                     BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;
```

Comment: Technically you're right, so I'm giving the answer. I'm using Xamarin and the underlying classes don't support TransportWithMessageCredential unfortunately.

Answer (score 8):

This can also be caused by the time being out of sync between client and server.  If a certificate or signed token is invalid based off of time, the same `An error occurred when verifying security for the message.` message may be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Just edit the .csproj file after adding the service reference and point these dependencies from 4.4.* to 4.6.*

```
<ItemGroup> <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Duplex" Version="4.6.*" /> 
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Http" Version="4.6.*" /> 
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.NetTcp" Version="4.6.*" /> 
    <PackageReference Include="System.ServiceModel.Security" Version="4.6.*" /> 
</ItemGroup>
```

and add this

```
 binding.Security.Mode = System.ServiceModel.BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
 binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName;
```