# An error occurred when verifying security for the message error when connection to SOAP service (.NET 4.7)

Tags: c#, .net, soap, soap-client

I was given a configuration of SOAP service, the configuration contained user name (in `domain\username` format), service address and password. I used Visual Studio, option `Add -> Service Reference` to add the service to my project. I have the following auto-generated configuration in the `App.config` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2" />
    </startup>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="DdpBinding" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://server_name:8080/Gordic/Ginis/Ws/test/HULT/DDP01/Ddp.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="DdpBinding"
                contract="GINIS_DDP_Test.DdpPortType" name="DdpPort" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

I added the following call to test the service.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string username = "DOMAIN\\username";
        string password = "password";

        WakeupRequest requestXml = new WakeupRequest();

        using (var client = new DdpPortTypeClient())
        {
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = username;
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = password;
            client.Wakeup();
        }
    }
}
```

However, the last line throws the following error.

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException: 'An error occurred when verifying security for the message.'
```

The developer of the software declares to implement the WS-Security standard, but I have no more information.

What should I update to make the system work?

Comment: start with a WSHttpBinding: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.wshttpbinding  in config: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/wcf/wshttpbinding

Comment: I tried this and I got the following error:
`The client and service bindings may be mismatched`

Comment: Okay, switch back to basicHttp binding and then add the security settings in the config: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24109173/578411

Comment: It seems to work now, thank you!